# How to sort a redis hash by values in keys

Tags: sorting, hash, redis

is there a good way in redis to get keys in a hash sorted by values? I've looked at the documentation and haven't found a straightforward way.

Also could someone please explain how sorting is achieved in redis, and what [this documentation](http://redis.io/commands/SORT#using-hashes-in-codebycode-and-codegetcode) is trying to say?

I have a very simple hash structure which is something like this:

"salaries" - "employee_1"  - "salary_amount"

I'd appreciate a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [`SORT`](http://redis.io/commands/SORT)'s documentation page:

> Returns or stores the elements contained in the list, set or sorted set at key

So you can't really use it to sort the fields by their values in a Hash data structure. To achieve your goal you should either do the sorting in your application's code after getting the Hash's contents or use a Redis-embedded Lua script for that purpose.

Edit: After speaking with @OfirLuzon we realized that there is another, perhaps even preferable, approach which would be to use a more suitable data structure for this purpose. Instead of storing the salaries in a Hash, you should consider using a Sorted Set in which each member is an employee ID and the score is the relevant salary. This will give you ordering, ranges and paging for "free" :)

Comment: I have written a blog post on how to model it. https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2019/12/modelling-sort-and-order-in-redis/

Answer (score 17):

You can achieve it by sorting a SET by one of your HASH fields. So you should create an indices SET of all of your hashes, and use the `BY` option.
Also, you can use `DESC` option to get the results sorted from high to low.

e.g.

```
localhost:6379> sadd indices h1 h2 h3 h4
(integer) 4
localhost:6379> hset h1 score 3
(integer) 1
localhost:6379> hset h2 score 2
(integer) 1
localhost:6379> hset h3 score 5
(integer) 1
localhost:6379> hset h4 score 1
(integer) 1
localhost:6379> sort indices by *->score
1) "h4"
2) "h2"
3) "h1"
4) "h3"
localhost:6379> sort indices by *->score desc
1) "h3"
2) "h1"
3) "h2"
4) "h4"
```

Comment: Great answer, although it requires keeping an additional data structure just for the purpose of sorting.