# Nodejs: Ioredis sort hash data

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

Hi Iam using ioredis node library to get and set data from redis.

I have data stored in redis in below format when I do

**hgetall**

```
1) "ff103ae9-1ce0-4a1e-989a-9393e39e4a8e"
2) "{\"id\":\"ff103ae9-1ce0-4a1e-989a-9393e39e4a8e\",\"company_id\":\"2d9dcbe0-a548-4c4a-8731-15b1866d4042\",\"location_id\":\"856f52a5-a11a-4151-a812-e25c73fc8a5b\",\"type\":\"\",\"name\":\"[ 001E5E09022772B4 ]\",\"model\":\"ST898ZBR\",\"status\":\"offline\",\"serial_number\":\"VR00ZN000230417\",\"mac_address\":\"00:1E:5E:09:02:27:72:B\",\"firmware_verison\":\"005C0046\",\"gateway_id\":\"93637030-8540-4e54-a877-f940aeb2efeb\",\"device_code\":\"SAU2AG1_GW-000C437620E8-ST898ZBR-001E5E09022772B4\",\"created_by\":\"\",\"updated_by\":\"2d9dcbe0-a548-4c4a-8731-15b1866d4042\",\"created_at\":\"2021-12-01T07:33:00.000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2021-02-15T06:20:55.006Z\",\"locations\":{\"id\":\"856f52a5-a11a-4151-a812-e25c73fc8a5b\",\"name\":\"Nikhil Site\",\"notes\":\"test\",\"type_id\":\"4ac73a11-9c11-4e2b-9e00-29598ab757ea\",\"company_id\":\"2d9dcbe0-a548-4c4a-8731-15b1866d4042\",\"address_id\":\"467c4d20-4849-484f-bce0-9f6b40ad3bc5\",\"container_id\":null,\"created_at\":\"2021-02-10T11:19:09.736Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2021-02-10T11:19:09.736Z\",\"created_by\":\"2d9dcbe0-a548-4c4a-8731-15b1866d4042\",\"updated_by\":\"2d9dcbe0-a548-4c4a-8731-15b1866d4042\",\"path\":{\"breadcrumb\":\"Nikhil Site\"}},\"gateway\":{\"id\":\"ce89073a-9ec6-48a7-8c60-40a5a0bb0e6a\",\"company_id\":\"2d9dcbe0-a548-4c4a-8731-15b1866d4042\",\"location_id\":\"856f52a5-a11a-4151-a812-e25c73fc8a5b\",\"type\":\"\",\"name\":\"\",\"model\":\"ST898ZBR\",\"status\":\"online\",\"serial_number\":\"VR00ZN000223409\",\"mac_address\":\"00:1E:5E:09:02:27:05:EC\",\"firmware_verison\":\"005C0046\",\"gateway_id\":\"93637030-8540-4e54-a877-f940aeb2efeb\",\"device_code\":\"dadse\",\"created_by\":\"\",\"updated_by\":\"\",\"created_at\":\"2021-03-02T08:16:00.000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2021-02-15T06:20:54.920Z\"}}"
3) "48822d7b-ec52-421a-a071-0722b41586fc"
4) "{\"id\":\"48822d7b-ec52-421a-a071-0722b41586fc\",\"company_id\":\"2d9dcbe0-a548-4c4a-8731-15b1866d4042\",\"location_id\":\"856f52a5-a11a-4151-a812-e25c73fc8a5b\",\"type\":\"gateway\",\"name\":\"22_01_2021_testgate\",\"model\":\"\",\"status\":\"\",\"serial_number\":\"22_01_2021_testgate\",\"mac_address\":null,\"firmware_verison\":\"\",\"gateway_id\":\"93637030-8540-4e54-a877-f940aeb2efeb\",\"device_code\":\"22_01_2021_testgate\",\"created_by\":\"2d9dcbe0-a548-4c4a-8731-15b1866d4042\",\"updated_by\":\"2d9dcbe0-a548-4c4a-8731-15b1866d4042\",\"created_at\":\"2022-10-01T08:54:00.000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2021-02-15T06:20:54.973Z\",\"locations\":{\"id\":\"856f52a5-a11a-4151-a812-e25c73fc8a5b\",\"name\":\"Nikhil Site\",\"notes\":\"test\",\"type_id\":\"4ac73a11-9c11-4e2b-9e00-29598ab757ea\",\"company_id\":\"2d9dcbe0-a548-4c4a-8731-15b1866d4042\",\"address_id\":\"467c4d20-4849-484f-bce0-9f6b40ad3bc5\",\"container_id\":null,\"created_at\":\"2021-02-10T11:19:09.736Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2021-02-10T11:19:09.736Z\",\"created_by\":\"2d9dcbe0-a548-4c4a-8731-15b1866d4042\",\"updated_by\":\"2d9dcbe0-a548-4c4a-8731-15b1866d4042\",\"path\":{\"breadcrumb\":\"Nikhil Site\"}},\"gateway\":{\"id\":\"ce89073a-9ec6-48a7-8c60-40a5a0bb0e6a\",\"company_id\":\"2d9dcbe0-a548-4c4a-8731-15b1866d4042\",\"location_id\":\"856f52a5-a11a-4151-a812-e25c73fc8a5b\",\"type\":\"\",\"name\":\"\",\"model\":\"ST898ZBR\",\"status\":\"online\",\"serial_number\":\"VR00ZN000223409\",\"mac_address\":\"dqasd\",\"firmware_verison\":\"005C0046\",\"gateway_id\":\"93637030-8540-4e54-a877-f940aeb2efeb\",\"device_code\":\"SAU2AG1_GW-001E5E01D26C-ST898ZBR-001E5E09022705EC\",\"created_by\":\"\",\"updated_by\":\"\",\"created_at\":\"2021-03-02T08:16:00.000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2021-02-15T06:20:54.920Z\"}}"
```

I want to sort the hashmap according to alphabetic order of **name** paramter

I have gone through https://github.com/luin/ioredis/issues/376 but didnt work as expected . Please help me

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31266743/how-to-sort-a-redis-hash-by-values-in-keys#31268541) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a redis hash by values in keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31266743/how-to-sort-a-redis-hash-by-values-in-keys)